# Casting objects in django model

Tags: python, django

I am making a django project with models.py having following code:

```
class Record(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)

class TTAMRecord(Record):
    client = models.ForeignKey(TTAMClient)

class TTAMClient(models.Model):
      ...

class Account(models.Model):
     records = models.ManyToManyField(Record)
      ...
```

I also have following code to insert a `TTAMRecord` into the `records` of an `Account`:

```
account = Account.objects.get(...)
client = TTAMClient.objects.create(...)
record = TTAMRecord.objects.create(..., client = client, ...)
account.records.add(record)
```

What I want to do(but can't) is to call the client within the record object of an account; e.g.:

```
account = Account.objects.get(...)
for record in account.records.all():
      client = record.client
         ...
```

However, if I am not allowed to do this, since `record` here is stored as a `Record` (which doesn't have client) type instead of `TTAMRecord`(which has client) type...

Any idea how to cast the object?
I want to use the more generic `Record` instead of `TTAMRecord` for some purposes not stated here...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As `Record` is not abstract model, it has its own table and life cycle as other models. However, you can access the corresponding client object as `record.ttamclient`, so you can change your line to

```
account = Account.objects.get(...)
for record in account.records.all():
    client = record.ttamclient
    ...
```

However, this is little cumbersome if you have multiple derived classes. In such cases you would have to know which derived class you are referring to and use the corresponding attribute name.

Answer (score 1):

If I understood your concept of "cast" it will not work in the way you described.

However, to get model inheritance to work you need to use [abstract models (see docs)](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#model-inheritance)

```
class Record(models.Model):
    # Some generic fields
    class Meta:
        abstract = True

class TTAMRecord(Record):
    client = models.ForeignKey(TTAMClient)
```

If you need both `Record` and `TTAMRecord` to be stored in `Account` you will need to use polymorphic relationships, that in Django it's called [Generic Relations (see docs)](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/contenttypes/#id1)

You will need an intermediary model to store these generic relations. So, basically you will have a `AccountRecord` and a `Account` model:

```
class AccountRecord(models.Model):
    content_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType)
    object_id = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    content_object = generic.GenericForeignKey('content_type', 'object_id')

class Account(models.Model):
    records = models.ManyToManyField(AccountRecord)
```

And so you can do:

```
account = Account.objects.get(...)
for record in account.records.all():
    record_content = record.content_object
    if isinstance(record_content, TTAMRecord):
        client = record_content.client
    else:
        # No client available
```